# PHP: Parsing postgre's default string time-stamp format

Tags: php, postgresql

I have problem to parse the following two time-stamp strings in a generic way?

```
$timestamp1 = "2013-10-15 19:05:18.756932+03";
$timestamp2 = "2013-10-15 19:05:18.756932+03:00";
```

I have this so far but it returns with `false`

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d HH:MM:SS frac "GMT"? [+-] hh ":"? MM?', $timestamp1);
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d HH:MM:SS frac "GMT"? [+-] hh ":"? MM?', $timestamp2);
```

What's wrong? Thank you.

P.S. I tried this `'Y-m-d HH:MM:SSfrac"GMT"?[+-]hh":"?MM?'`, this `''Y-m-d HH:MM:SS[0-9]+"GMT"?[+-]hh":"?MM?'` and this `'Y-m-d HH:MM:SS [0-9] "GMT"? [+-] hh ":"? MM?'` but it always fails.

Comment: What does this correspond to -- `19:05:18.756932+03`?

Comment: @Amal Murali 19:05:18, .756932 is fractional part for a second and +03 is timezone offset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the last part is a timezone offset, `Y-m-d H:i:s.ue` should work.

If this is posgre's default format you will probably need to handle the case when there are no fractional seconds (`2013-10-15 19:05:18+03`) with `Y-m-d H:i:se`.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your format string.

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.uP', $timestamp1);
```

Here is the documentation for the format string options:
[PHP: DateTime::createFromFormat Manual](http://php.net/manual/it/datetime.createfromformat.php)